# how to make that when the data on the server changed independently of the reducer application also changed

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux

For example, there is an application. The user sits on the main page and needs to understand that there are new orders.
I download data only at the beginning of app using redux-thunk. It seems I can not subscribe to the update with a server change change.
If it's impossible to do this on redux-thunk, what libraries do you use or approaches?

Comment: Broad questions like this are hard to answer, and we usually like to see that you have put in work trying to solve it before asking others. What have you tried, and what code are you having trouble with?

Comment: To update the reducer, I decided to render this.props.dispatch (fetchData () and before shouldComponentUpdate() and then slow the application before render component. And the main disadvantage is that if I'm in another component of the reducer but can update myself

Comment: There are two options: polling or using sockets.

Comment: redux saga is not capable of this?